# Why can't I retrieve the cookies exchanged from my AngularJS mobile application with the server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, cookies

I have built a hybrid mobile application based on Ionic, AngularJS and Cordova and I want to retrieve the cookies sent back from a server after the `$http` request and I can't!

Invoking the backend server through the browser I can see, using the developer tools, some cookies were created.
How can I invoke the same server from my AngularJS mobile application and retrieve these cookies?

I'm trying the ngCookies module:

```
<script src="lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

And the application module seems to be configured correctly:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCookies'])
```

As well as the controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$cookieStore', function($scope, $http, $cookieStore) {

    $scope.signIn = function() {    
        $http.post(url, inputObject)
        .success(function (data, status, header) {
            console.log("======> Cookies: " + header('Set-Cookie'));
            console.log("Cookies are: " + JSON.stringify($cookieStore));
        })    
    };
}])
```

The result is the first console log displays only a cookie (the browser developer tools displays more), and the `$cookieStore` shows an empty object!!

Nevertheless, the cookies are got because they are sent back to the server in an implicit way if I invoke it again from my App.
Then, why the `$cookieStore` did not show them?

The problem is the cookies implicitly exchanged with the server are deleted when the application is stopped (because most of them are session cookies), so I wanted to read them once they are created, store it locally (e.g. `localStorage`) for avoiding its deletion when the application is stopped, and assign them to the backend request when the application is starting again.

Can I do that?? How can I do it? I'd need help for retrieving the cookies and also for adding them again to a new `$http` request.

Many thanks!!

Sergi

Comment: @Aadil-keshwani did you ever figure this out?